# Ubuntu / Python support lifecycle

Tags: python, lts, canonical, support

I am wondering what the official support stance is for Python with Ubtuntu.  For example, Ubuntu 20 LTS ships with Python 3.8 and standard support will last through April 2025 but Python 3.8 support ends October 14, 2024.  Is Canonical on the hook for any security patches after 10/14/2024 until standard support ends or even for five years after with paid support?  Is it possible to upgrade to something like Python 3.11 and make it the default and remove 3.8?  I can't find any place that says that newer versions are supported.

Comment: Canonical will keep it updated. If you change default Python, you'll ruin the system.

Comment: "Ubuntu 20" is the name of an Ubuntu Core release which ships without any (user-accessible) Python at all, so that question is moot. Perhaps you meant Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Yes, I was referring to 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

"*Is Canonical on the hook for any security patches [to Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8] after 10/14/2024 until standard support ends or even for five years after with paid support?*"

This community will continue to provide Standard Support to Python 3.8 until April 2025.

The Ubuntu Security Team will continue to provide security patches (only) to Python 3.8 for free (in Main) until April 2025, and then via Pro (in esm) until April 2030.

---

"*Is it possible to upgrade to something like Python 3.11 and make it the default and remove 3.8?*"

Do not do that. It will break your system horribly. This community will NOT provide any support for that kind of abomination. The Ubuntu Security Team will NOT provide 3.11 patches in the 20.04 repositories.

If you want to use Python 3.11, do so in a virtual environment OR migrate to a newer release of Ubuntu. Python 3.11 will be in Ubuntu 23.04, to be released in April 2023.

Comment: Thank you and this aligns with my understanding.  Do you know if there are any official statements by Canonical in regards to this that I can present to my security teams?

Comment: You can use any python version in an environment, there are several python solutions. (anaconda,virtualenv [and others](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/))

Comment: The point is my org will flag python 3.8 as obsolete when it goes end of life if it is still installed.

Comment: See https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle : Look for the paragraph that says "*For each Ubuntu LTS release, Canonical maintains the Base Packages and provides security updates, including kernel livepatching, for a period of ten years....*." That's a mighty clear official statement.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose this is the best answer.